# Nullrefererencepointer Exception when adding values in list box through Array or List in c#

Tags: c#, listbox, nullpointerexception

I just want to add the names of Astrology Stars in `Listbox` in Xaml Code

```
public MainPage()
    {
    string[] StarsName = {"Aries","Taurus","Aquarius","Pisces"};

        List<string> Stars = new List<string>(StarsName);

        foreach (string abc in StarsName)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(abc.ToString());
        }
    }
```

......

and then i tried by making a list of StarName

```
                  foreach (string abc in Stars)
                 {
                   listBox1.Items.Add(abc.ToString());
                 }
```

Every time a run the code ,there is `NullReferenceException` at following line

```
                 listBox1.Items.Add(abc.ToString());
```

Further More I will like know,how can i Bind This data Directly to listview in XAML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place your code *after*  the call to `InitializeComponent()`.
That method is responsible for creating the instances of the UI elements. If you try to access them earlier, they are still `null`, hence the `NullReferenceException` when trying to access `listBox1`.

Furthermore, your code contains some redundant stuff:

1. Calling `ToString()` on a `string` is unnecessary. Remove it.
2. Creating an array just to create a list from it is unnecessary. You can use a collection initializer instead.

Comment: Yes, i added InitializeComponent() and it solved my problem ..ThanxAlot